# TryCast using an indirect type?

Tags: vb.net, casting, system.reflection

Is there anyway to specify the object type for TryCast indirectly?
An example of what I'd like to do (NOTE: This does *not* work - I get a syntax error saying "Type 'T' is not defined".)

```
Public Sub FOO()
    Dim SomObject As New Object

    For Each t As Type In Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        TryCast(SomObject, t)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The second parameter is the `Type` you trying to cast to not a string.

Comment: Yes, I know that's why my code doesn't work, but what can I pass here? I tried `doc=TryCast(window.Document, t)` and it doesn't like that either.  Says "Class T is not defined"

Comment: An assembly can contain more than one namespace and a given namespace can span multiple assemblies, so that code may only do a fraction of what you want.  Also, if the object you start with is from elsewhere, its not likely anything will be found in the `ExecutingAssembly`

Comment: The object is a window's file explorer window that has an active shell extension.  We have a document management program that is basically a wrapper for windows file explorer.  This program's windows show up as part of the `exShell.Windows` collection and I can use the `IWebBrowser2` interface to query the `.LocationName` and know what window I'm dealing with - so I know it's valid and can be worked with.  However the `.Document` property doesn't identify as `IShellFolderViewDual3` and throws an exception trying to cast as such, so I'm trying to determine what type I can cast it to.

Comment: ...and that is why the Winforms solution from before did not work out of the box for you.  I suspected a Shell Extension was involved. *basically a wrapper* means it may not expose any of the Shell properties or interfaces you are looking for.  (BTW `@varname` wont compile)

Comment: Yes it's a shell extension (I found the entry in the registry for the shell extension). And yes, I believe these objects were the issue with the typecast.  I'll fix the @varname, it was carried over from the C example - thank you!  I actually tested creating an object from that guid, which worked, but didn't expose any useful interfaces. Since casting the object as a ShellBrowserWindow works even though that interface isn't exposed when created from GUID, I figured I would try the brute force TryCast the .document member to all shell32 types approach...see if anything works.

Comment: I edited the question to more directly reflect what I was trying to ask, as it is not necessarily limited to the scope of this particular problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190877/why-cant-you-use-gettype-when-casting

Comment: @Plutonix FWIW the brute force TryCast approach did work in that I was able to cast the `.Document` member to a single interface from the Shell32 library. `DShellFolderViewEvents_Event` is the only thing that TryCast worked on.  Not really sure what that means, but at least it gives me the next direction to look in!